# Get arguments and returning value from ASM code

Tags: assembly, arguments

I'm investigating some windows internals and since I couldn't find any documentation I started going through the dissasembled code. Basically what I would like to know is how to determine the arguments and the returning value of a function:

These are the instructions before the call:

```
MOV EAX,DWORD PTR DS:[ESI+64]
LEA ECX,DWORD PTR SS:[EBP-4]
PUSH ECX
PUSH DWORD PTR DS:[EAX+4]
PUSH DWORD PTR DS:[EAX]
PUSH DWORD PTR DS:[ESI+60]
CALL <FUNCTION CALL>
```

---

This is the stack after the 4 pushes:

000000C0 (4 byte Literal?)

001CEAF0 (An address in the heap?)

000001B8 (4 Byte Literal?)

0019F2FC (An address in the heap?)

Answer (score 0):

Given that you are investigating Microsoft Windows internals, it seems likely that the calling convention used is `stdcall`; Wikipedia notes:

> `stdcall` is the standard calling convention for the Microsoft Win32 API and for Open Watcom C++.

For more information, see the Wikipedia page on [calling conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#stdcall) and this [WikiBook entry](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Disassembly/Calling_Convention_Examples#STDCALL).

So in your case, this would correspond to the following C code:

```
eax = function(0x0019F2FC, 0x1B8, 0x001CEAF0, 0xC);
```

Comment: The code snippet is full of `PUSH` instructions, what makes you think this would be fastcall?

Comment: Maybe the extra information I provided could help??

Comment: @Jester: Thank you, I don't know what I've been thinking there. Reworked my answer.

Comment: Great, thanks! Altough, is there any way to know for certain the parameters' type? I know that the first and third parameters are pointers (i've checked, the memory region exists) and the other two are literals (maybe a buffer size??)

Comment: Unfortunately, no. You can trace back where the arguments come from (e.g. from a function with a known API), you can look at the memory at those addresses to figure out what data it contains, or you can disassemble the function and look at what it does with its parameters. Your buffer size guess seams reasonable, but it's hard to be sure without further investigation.